# Não percebo uma resolução de ordenação

Tags: java, if

O professor pediu o exercício seguinte:

"Escreva um programa que recebe três pontuações (números inteiros); ordena essas pontuações
utilizando instruções if e escreve as três por ordem crescente no ecrã."

Tentei fazer à minha maneira sozinho mas acabei por ficar enrolado durante quase 30 minutos perdido no meio de tantos if's e else's e fui ver a resolução que o professor disponibilizou,mas não consigo entende-la.A resolução é a seguinte:

```
System . out . println("Indique a 1ª pontuação:");
    int pontuacao1=scanner.nextInt();
    System . out . println("Indique a 2ª pontuação:");
    int pontuacao2 = scanner.nextInt();
    System . out . println("Indique a 3ª pontuação:");
    int pontuacao3 = scanner.nextInt();

     if (pontuacao2 < pontuacao1) 
    { 
        int valor = pontuacao1; 
        pontuacao1 = pontuacao2; 
        pontuacao2 = valor; 
    } 
    if (pontuacao3 < pontuacao2) 
    { 
        int valor = pontuacao2; 
        pontuacao2 = pontuacao3; 
        pontuacao3 = valor; 
        if (pontuacao2 < pontuacao1) 
        { 
            int valor2 = pontuacao1; 
            pontuacao1 = pontuacao2; 
            pontuacao2 = valor; 
        } 
    } 

    System.out.print(pontuacao1 + ", " + pontuacao2 + ", " + pontuacao3);
```

A primeira parte de input de valores eu percebo mas a partir do if é que não. Alguém pode explicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variável temporária**

A váriavel `valor` serve para temporariamente armazenar um valores para não perdê-lo.

Vamos lá,

Recebemos três valores, vamos por exemplo supor: `11, 5, 3`.

Agora precisamos ordená-los, por isso vamos fazer as comparações com as estruturas condicionais `if`:

`if (pontuacao2 > pontacao1)`: Vamos comparar de a segunda pontuacao é maior que a primeira. No nosso caso não certo? Então vamos perguntar ao próximo `if`,

`if (pontuacao3 < pontuacao2)`: A terceira pontuação é menor que a segunda? SIM. Então entramos na estrutura,

Como a última posição é menor que a segunda elas deveriam estar trocadas certo? Sim. Porém se apenas fizermos:

```
pontuacao2 = pontuacao3;
pontacao3 = pontuacao2;
```

O que será que acontece? Vamos pensar:

// `pontuacao2` vai receber o valor de `pontuacao3`, logo `pontuacao2` vai virar `3`,

// Agora `pontuacao`3 recebe o valor de `pontuacao2`, mas perceba, `pontuacao2` agora é `3`, logo as duas variáveis vao acabar tendo o valor `3`.

Onde foi parar nosso `5`? Nesse caso perdemos ele. Por isso de uma variável temporária, para que possamos temporariamente segurar o `5` para darmos ele à outra `pontuacao`. Vejamos:

```
int valor = pontuacao2; 
pontuacao2 = pontuacao3; 
pontuacao3 = valor;
```

// Agora temporariamente armazenamos o valor de `pontuacao2` em `valor`, nesse caso, `5`

// Então passamos o valor de `pontuacao3` para `pontuacao2`, ela recebe o `3`
 // Por fim, ainda temos nosso `5` guardado, em `valor`, agora só passarmos ele para `pontuacao3`. Prontinho.

Só repetir isso para a próxima condição: `pontuacao2 < pontuacao1`, que no caso também é verdadeira.

**Agora vamos pensar na estrutura dos `if`**

Temos primeiro uma pergunta, se pont2 < pont1. Devemos fazer essa pergunta, no caso de condição verdadeira, entramos no `if` e invertemos as posições.

Agora temos uma outra pergunta, se pont3 < pont2, por que nesse caso usamos outro `if` ao invés de um `else if`? Usamos outro `if` porque queremos obrigatoriamente realizar esta verificação independentemente do resultado da primeira.

Agora, por que o terceiro `if` está dentro do segundo? Perceba, essa condição SÓ será testada caso a segunda seja válida. Se pont2 não é menor que pont1 e pont3 não é menor que pont2 significa que os números já estão ordenados, desse modo realizar uma terceira verificação seria desnecessário, então assim acabamos por otimizar nosso código.